how to resolve dependency errors with Gradle
I have configured my dependencies in my build.gradle file, but when I call the imports, it generates dependency errors. I've already updated Gradle, refreshed, restarted Gradle, and cleaned it, but it still doesn't recognize them. I also updated the version in the gradle-wrapper.properties file, but I haven't been able to resolve the dependency problem.
dependencies {

    // Use JUnit Jupiter for testing.
    testImplementation libs.junit.jupiter

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'

    // This dependency is used by the application.
    implementation libs.guava


    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    implementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.23.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.3'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
    implementation 'io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:5.9.2'

    testImplementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0' // Para manejo de strings y utilidades
    testImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.32' // Para logging
    testImplementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.32' // Implementación simple para logging
    testImplementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:4.21.0' // Para Screenplay
 
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-core
    implementation 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:4.1.20'


    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-screenplay
    implementation 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-screenplay:4.1.20'


    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.serenity-bdd/serenity-junit
    implementation 'net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit:4.1.20'
}



I updated my Gradle, reconfigured the build.gradle file, refreshed the project, found the settings.json file, updated the version in the gradle-wrapper.properties file, and refreshed Visual Studio. I expected that this would resolve the dependency error, but it didn't work.
